# Dell P170S monitor shows vertical red, pink, blue or green lines upon watching youtube

Tags: video, hdmi, raspberry-pi, vga, adapter

The video that shows this best is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ps-0f0K6izM), at around 0:16. The red lines pass across the screen left-to-right. They also appear and disappear.

I am using KDE Plasma Manjaro on a Raspberry Pi 400, and [this HDMI source to VGA adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adapter-Compatible-Computer-Projector-Raspberry/dp/B07XZ22KCD). I have tried rebooting the computer, and resetting the monitor. The color of the lines also depend on the color of the video. For example, if a video is, say magenta, the lines would appear blue. This problem does not occur with static color videos, nor with images. Unfortunately, I cannot use my phone camera to capture the problem, and I cannot take a screenshot of it.

Are the lines a problem with YouTube, video playback, the adaptor, or my monitor, and how can I fix it.

Comment: Do they happen with other videos on YouTube or from your PC ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.